# scaleable swfs and javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I managed to track down the following JavaScript that will properly load and display a scalable SWF. It works great, but now I am unable to insert the code to display static image if browser doesn't support Flash.

I'd like a solution that I can insert in existing JavaScript function, and baring that, a solution that makes swf scalable and with alternate static image. You can see in action at: stevevangelder.com/interactive, without the static image.

Is it me, or is a SFW always a problem? And I'm a flash guy!

```
function ImageClick8(){
  console.log("page8");

  var img = document.getElementById('whiteBacker').style.display = "block"; 
  var img = document.getElementById('projectContainer8').style.display = "block";        
  var img = document.getElementById('interButtonsContainer').style.zIndex = "-12";

  var flashvars = false; 
  var params = {}; 
  var attributes = {}; 

  swfobject.embedSWF("projectFiles/eyeOnTheBall.swf", "eyeContainer", "100%", "100%", 
                     "9.0.0", "swf/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SWfObject2 provides a simple way to do this, and you should still be able to accomplish scaling:

[Read about SwfObject2 Here.  Look down the page for alternative content and express install.](http://www.adobe.com/mena_fr/devnet/flashplayer/articles/alternative_content.html)